# Why "out" is needed in golang.org/x/crypto/nacl/box

Tags: go, encryption, cryptography

I started to use the [package box](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/nacl/box?tab=doc) in Go and got a little bit confused in Seal Function:

According to [Documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/nacl/box?tab=doc#Seal):

```
/*Seal appends an encrypted and authenticated copy of message to out, which will be Overhead
bytes longer than the original and must not overlap it. The nonce must be unique for each
distinct message for a given pair of keys. */

func Seal(out, message []byte, nonce *[24]byte, peersPublicKey, privateKey *[32]byte) []byte
```

But as we can see the func already returns a Byte Array containing encrypted and authenticated message

In the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/nacl/box?tab=doc#example-package), this func is used this way:

```
var nonce [24]byte
if _, err := io.ReadFull(crypto_rand.Reader, nonce[:]); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}

msg := []byte("Alas, poor Yorick! I knew him, Horatio")
// This encrypts msg and appends the result to the nonce.
encrypted := box.Seal(nonce[:], msg, &nonce, recipientPublicKey, senderPrivateKey)
```

---

So I have a few questions:

- Why pass the values inside nonce, since nonce is the 3th argument?
- Why "out" is needed?

Comment: You quoted the answer already - `Seal appends an encrypted and authenticated copy of message to out`, so passing in `nonce` returns the result prefixed by the `nonce`, which is common so that you don't need to store the nonce separately.

Comment: To answer the "Why 'out' is needed?" part: It is completely un-needed, Seal could just return what it computed. But in this case Seal would have to allocate a []byte for its result and allocations are costly. Passing in an `out` (which can be used allocation-free if large enough) allows to write code  which reduces memory allocations. This type of operations benefit a _lot_ from keeping alloc counts low.

Comment: Hi @Volker, could you explain more? 
Going deeper in the stacktrace we can find this two lines:
https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/0ec3e9974c59449edd84298612e9f16fa13368e8/nacl/secretbox/secretbox.go#L90
https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/0ec3e9974c59449edd84298612e9f16fa13368e8/nacl/secretbox/secretbox.go#L119

Which tells me that the func already returns what it computes, by allocating a []byte for its result

Comment: @FilipeOliveira: the source you linked to contradicts what you're saying -- it doesn't allocate if it has sufficient capacity.

Comment: There really is not much to see. The API is the way it is. There are good reasons for the out parameter (JimB and I gave you two) but if your problem doesn't benefit from it (because you do not need the nonce or you don't care about allocs): Just ignore it.

Comment: Thank you guys 
I now see: https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/0ec3e9974c59449edd84298612e9f16fa13368e8/nacl/secretbox/secretbox.go#L62


I forgot to mention that its one of my first interactions with Go.
So I was a little confused by the usage of that parameter:
* The applicability of this parameter in the Seal func, since other languages don't specify it [php](https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium-php) [js](https://github.com/tonyg/js-nacl/blob/cc70775cfc9d68a04905ca65c7f179b33a18066e/nacl_cooked.js#L147)

But now I see that is related only to the memory allocation

Comment: @Volker I liked you first comment, it's very explanatory and helped to guide my thoughts. If you want to give an answer to this question I will accept it as correct